# Drawing images in c#

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to draw an image in my Windows Form Application. I drew instead of the picture some rectangles but I want to replace them somehow with a certain image.
I added the whole code and the problem is in the draw function. Can anybody help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using Microsoft.Win32;



namespace kiralyno
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public static int p = 1;

    public static int o = 1;


    public float[] x1 = new float[80000];

    public float[] y1 = new float[80000];


    public string hely = " ";
    public int db = 0;

    public int[] v = new int[80000];
    public static string a;
    public string s = " ";

    public static int n = Form1.n;
    public float x = 0, y = 0, w = 450 / n, h = 450 / n;

    public int helyes(int i, int k)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= k - 1; j++)
            if ((v[j] == i) || (Math.Abs(k - j) == Math.Abs(i - v[j])))
                return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    public void kiir(int k)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
        {

            s += Convert.ToString(v[j]);


            if (j != n) s += " ";


        }
        a = s;
        megoldas.Items.Add(a);

        s = "";
        a = "";


    }


    public void back(int k)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            if (helyes(i, k) == 1)
            {




                v[k] = i;
                if (k == n)
                {

                    kiir(k);
                    draw();

                   Thread.Sleep(500);
                    sakktabla(0, 0, w, h);
                    db++;

                }
                else back(k + 1);


            }

        }
    }


    public void draw()
    {

       // Image newImage = Image.FromFile("D:/Akos/Visual/Projects/kiralyno/kir.png");

         Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();


        for (int m = 1; m <= n; m++)
        {


             g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Blue), x1[v[m]], y1[m], w, h);
              g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x1[v[m]], y1[m], w, h);

            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

    }


    public Form2()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void sakktabla(float x, float y, float w, float h)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {

                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                {

                    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
                    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black), x, y, w, h);
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, w, h);

                    x1[p] = x;

                    x = x + 450 / n;


                }
                else
                {
                    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
                    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.White), x, y, w, h);
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, x, y, w, h);


                    x1[p] = x;

                    x = x + 450 / n;

                }
                p++;

            }
            y1[o] = y;
            for (int m = 1; m <= n; m++)
            {
                y1[n * m + o] = y1[o];

            }
            o++;


            y = y + 450 / n;

            x = 0;

        }
    }


    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        sakktabla(0, 0, w, h);


    }

    private void Form2_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();

    }



    private void megoldas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "";
        back(1);

        if (db == 0) megoldas.Items.Add("Nincs megoldas!");
        string c = Convert.ToString(db);
        megoldas.Items.Add(c+" db megoldas van");
        megoldas.Enabled = false;


    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "";
        back(1);

        if (db == 0) megoldas.Items.Add("Nincs megoldas!");
        string c = Convert.ToString(db);
        megoldas.Items.Add(c + " db megoldas van");
        megoldas.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Replace them with what?  You are not being very clear about what you were expecting.  Also you have variables n, x1, y1, w, h here and its not obvious what they are.

Comment: Avoid CreateGraphics.  Use the paint event instead.  You don't need a new Pen, just use Pens.Blue.  Use a timer instead of Sleep, which blocks.

Comment: I changed the new Pen and it works fine thanks!

Comment: I also uploaded the whole code for everything to be clear.

Comment: Adding all your code doesn't make your question clearer, I'm afraid. We need to know specifically what your problem is and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
private void DrawImageRect(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Create image.
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile("SampImag.jpg");

    // Create rectangle for displaying image.
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 450, 150);

    // Draw image to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, destRect);
}
```

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure why you got down ranked when I understood your question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to draw it yourself, use: [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In general it's usually easier to use a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx), though.

Comment: if I use PictureBox how to draw multiple images on some particular points?

Comment: You could just move the picturebox where you wanted using the Position and Size members. For multiple images use multiple pictureboxes.